# Use of words with similar meanings

Tags: grammar

Would it be correct to use the words "pain and lamentation" in the same sentence?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do whatever you like!

Comment: Note that many people object that using two similar words, joined by "and", is "redundant" and hence a mortal sin.  But such redundant wording is a powerful tool in the author's toolkit.  It should be (within reason) celebrated, not denounced.

Comment: You just have done.

Answer (score 1):

These two words don't really have similar meanings.  Pain is the feeling; lamentation, is the expression of it.  But of course you may use them in the same sentence.  [Others](https://books.google.com/books?id=3qhQuWPNUckC&pg=PA206&dq=%22pain%20and%20lamentation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCGoVChMInpyww6CJyQIVCUsmCh2_rgiJ#v=onepage&q=%22pain%20and%20lamentation%22&f=false) have:

> The Orphic religion presents the same Janus head: the one face
>   discloses **pain and lamentation**, the other confidence and joy, and
>   the two are united in the idea that above the endless transience of
>   all tellurian [earthly] existence there dwells the consoling eternity
>   of uranian [heavenly] life.

Note the second related pair of words -- *confidence* and *joy*.